# Lua generic for loop getting dynamic variable value

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-table

I have a table with dynamic keys and values, and I wanna loop thru it with a generic for loop, however, since the tables values are dynamic, how can I get the value of the dynamic variable? I hope this makes any sense. Let me show it with code to better explain.

```
Local weapons = {
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_PISTOL')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('component_at_pi_supp_02'), [Strings['flash_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_PI_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_PISTOL_VARMOD_LUXE') },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_PISTOL50')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP_02'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_PI_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_PISTOL50_VARMOD_LUXE') },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_COMBATPISTOL')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_PI_SUPP'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_PI_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = nil },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_APPISTOL')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_PI_SUPP'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_PI_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_APPISTOL_VARMOD_LUXE') },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_HEAVYPISTOL')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_PI_SUPP'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_PI_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_HEAVYPISTOL_VARMOD_LUXE') },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_VINTAGEPISTOL')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_PI_SUPP'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = nil, [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = nil },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_SMG')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_PI_SUPP'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_SMG_VARMOD_LUXE') },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_MICROSMG')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP_02'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_PI_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_MICROSMG_VARMOD_LUXE') },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_ASSAULTSMG')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP_02'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = nil },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_ASSAULTRIFLE')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP_02'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_AFGRIP'), skin = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_ASSAULTRIFLE_VARMOD_LUXE') },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_CARBINERIFLE')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_AFGRIP'), skin = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_CARBINERIFLE_VARMOD_LUXE') },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_ADVANCEDRIFLE_VARMOD_LUXE') },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_SPECIALCARBINE')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP_02'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_AFGRIP'), skin = nil },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_BULLPUPRIFLE')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_AFGRIP'), skin = nil },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_ASSAULTSHOTGUN')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_AFGRIP'), skin = nil },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_HEAVYSHOTGUN')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP_02'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_AFGRIP'), skin = nil },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_BULLPUPSHOTGUN')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP_02'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_AFGRIP'), skin = nil },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_PUMPSHOTGUN')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_SR_SUPP'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = nil },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_MARKSMANRIFLE')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_AFGRIP'), skin = nil },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_SNIPERRIFLE')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP_02'), [Strings['flash_name']]  = nil, [Strings['grip_name']] = nil, skin = nil },
    [GetHashKey('WEAPON_COMBATPDW')] = { [Strings['supp_name']] = nil, [Strings['flash_name']]  = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH'), [Strings['grip_name']] = GetHashKey('COMPONENT_AT_AR_AFGRIP'), skin = nil }
}

local Strings = {
    ['removed_supp'] = 'You removed your suppressor',
    ['removed_grip'] = 'You removed your weapon grip',
    ['removed_flash'] = 'You removed your weapon flashlight',
    ['no_fit'] = '%s does not fit your current weapon',
    ['removed'] = 'You have removed your %s',
    ['used'] = 'You have used your %s',
    ['webhookMSG'] = '**Spiller Navn:** %s \n**ID:** %s \n**Tried to spawn:** %s',
    ['supp_name'] = 'suppressor',
    ['supp_Rname'] = 'Suppressor',
    ['supp_desc'] = 'Can be used to make your weapon silent when shooting.',
    ['flash_name'] = 'flashlight',
    ['flash_Rname'] = 'Flashlight',
    ['flash_desc'] = 'Can be attached to a weapon to give it a flashlight.',
    ['grip_name'] = 'grip',
    ['grip_Rname'] = 'Grip',
    ['grip_desc'] = 'Can be attached on a weapon to get a better grip.',
    ['choice_use'] = 'Use'
}
```

As you can see in the table, the values depend on the value from Strings table. So if I wanna do a for loop, and get the correct value how would I do it?

```
for k,v in pairs(weapons) do
   if k == GetHashKey('WEAPON_PISTOL') then
      print(v.<what here>) -- how do i get the v.Strings['supp_name']?
   end
end
```

I hope this makes any sense, if not, please ask in the comments.

Thanks, Ossie

Comment: indexing with a dot is only possibe if the table key is a valid Lua identifier. if you want to use anything else use square brackets. you can also use variables as table keys. please read the Lua manual

Answer (score 3):

just use `v[Strings['supp_name']]`

Comment: Yep thanks, figured that out just now :D